# Asynchronous Programming with Threads

Tags: c#

Prior to `Tasks` and `Async/Await` I/O and CPU intensive tasks were done using threads right?

With that being the case how is/was asynchronous programming done using threads alone without the use of more modern features in the CLR.

I ask because I have a project that needs to be compiled for a lower version of the .NET Framework. I believe it's version 3. And I'd like to learn more about asynchronous programming using threads alone.

Where's the best place to start and what resources would be useful?

**Edit:** It appears I'm being a little misunderstood. What I want to know is where's the best places to learn about asynchronous programming using just threads. I am already aware of Tasks and Async/Await and use them a lot in my projects.

Comment: I/O intensive apps used, and still use, IOCP. Also, Tasks and Async/Await do not "supersede" threads as you seem to imply it. They are merely another layer of abstraction, above threads.

Comment: @WilliamAndrewMontgomery yes I'm aware of that. Threads can do what Tasks and Async/Await can do ... albeit with a little more work. This is what I want to learn how to do.

Comment: Tasks are backed by threads. It's just a cleaner high level API

Comment: @TGH please see edit to my question.

Comment: Why the votes to close? This IS a programming related question ... or are threads no longer a part of "programming"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has been mentioned before, `Tasks` and `Async/Await` still use threads. They simply abstract away the finer points of creating, running, and joining threads.

This is a pretty decent tutorial on Threading for older versions of .NET: [MSDN Threading Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

You will be using the `System.Threading` library.

Answer (score 1):

> Prior to Tasks and Async/Await I/O and CPU intensive tasks were done using threads right?

They still are.

I/O intensive had a non blocking mechanism since day one in .NET - basically because Windows always had it. THings like Socket's SELECT method go back way way way long time.

And taks run in threads at the end as this is the ONLY way to run multiple things at the same time: having OS backed threads. Tasks are just a (very good) API on top of threads to abstract their use away.

> Where's the best place to start and what resources would be useful?

Documentation. System.THreading namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The [System.Threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.aspx) namespace has been in .NET since the beginning so have a read up about that on MSDN.  Classes in .NET that help with threading (such as backgroundworker) prettymuch all use the functionality from this namespace anyway.

To start a new thread you do [Thread.Start()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/a9fyxz7d.aspx), then go from there.